# Cannot find resource in Sub Main started WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have WPF application in VB.NET which have Application Framework turned off and is starting from Sub Main method.

```
Public Module Bootstrapper
  <STAThread>
  Sub Main()
    Dim app As New System.Windows.Application
    AddHandler app.Startup, AddressOf Application_Startup
    AddHandler app.Exit, AddressOf Application_Exit
    app.MainWindow = New MainWindow
    app.Run(app.MainWindow)
  End Sub
End Module
```

I also have window for user login, which is shown from constructor of main window. Here is fragment of its XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="UserIDTextBox"
               Grid.Column="1" 
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding UserID, 
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Style="{StaticResource ErrorToolTipStyle}"/>
```

When I start application, XamlParseException is raised: Cannot find resource named 'ErrorToolTipStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.  I am sure that it is caused by starting application from Sub Main, not by specifying main window in project properties. Any ideas how to solve this except not starting from Sub Main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after hours of research. If you want to manually start your WPF application, **don't try to create your own startup class/module or custom Application class by any means**. Any attempts like this will result in strange runtime errors, inability to use application-wide resources and lot of similar malformed errors.

Instead just remove StartupUri element from your Application.xaml and handle Startup event in your project's Application class, where you put everything you wanted to put in Sub Main. This is only working and reliable solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Your WPF application has also an App.xaml where you can add your resource dictionaries.

Without it you should add this resource to the page/window/control from where you have the UserIDTextBox.

Comment: Of course I have that style defined in App.xaml inside <Application.Resources>...

Comment: But you're overriding it from the bootstrapper (new New System.Windows.Application). Also the OnStart  and OnExit methods are overridden.

Comment: You could try instead of creating a new instance of system.Windows.Application use the existing one by referencing it: